# css's Visited property is not available. I'm making a note box and I need your advice

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

[image]

I'm going to make a simple note box. 
When you click the inbox, the inbox, the inbox, etc. with that picture, 
I want to have a solid line around Div and components. 
Perhaps it is a border attribute. But I don't know how to approach css. Currently, the Visited attribute is not applied. I'm curious about your opinion.

Each span is a receiving box, a sending box, a new writing system, and a friend management.

```
<div style="">
    <span id="R">수신함</span>
    <span id="S">송신함</span>
    <a href="" id="write"><span>새로작성</span></a>
    <span id="friend">친구관리</span>
</div>


 #write:visited{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: `:visited` will check the `href` to see if it's in your history - ie have you visited that link.  1) you don't have an href so there's nothing to check 2) semantically, you're not using the `a` as an `a` but rather as a `<button>` so there's nowhere for your browser to have "visited" in order to apply the ":visited"

Answer (score 1):

Browsers limit the styles that can be set for `:visited` links for security reasons.

The styles available for `:visited` links are;

- color
- background-color
- border-color (and border-color for separate sides)
- outline color
- column-rule-color
- the color parts of fill and stroke

All other styles are inherited from `a:link`